# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. > Process 'command 'C:\FlutterSdk\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

/C:/FlutterSdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fl_chart-0.50.5/lib/src/chart/pie_chart/pie_chart.dart:42:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/FlutterSdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  Try calling using ?. instead.
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\FlutterSdk\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\FlutterSdk\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             38.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 3):

use `flutter pub cache repair` command

because flutter stores the data in its own storage, and if it gets full, it will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

lib provider had breaking changes when migrating to flutter 3 but didn't bump the major version, you can try locking the version in pubspec.yml or migrate to flutter 3 as well...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is one another similar error which indicates syntax error inside dart code. Full error text is like below:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/users/elmar/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             17.3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

You need to find and correct sytax error and app wil run without any error after that.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to **flutter pub get**, I successfully used this method